# Whatsapp Manager number verification pending

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am trying to add my number in whatsapp manager but it dont show any option for code or call. It just land me to list view and shows number status as pending. My business is already verified. have anybody experienced similar issue?

I have added number and it should send SMS code or call on given number but it redirect to page where number shows in list view and status pending. I have tried at least 3 different numbers. Nono of them is on whatsapp business before.